# Connecting private set of quorum of 3 nodes on stellar test network

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, testnet

I have a 3 nodes running on a private network paraphrase and all of them are validators. Able to send the transactions over horizon.

Now, can I connect my quorum of 3 validators with test-network ? Is it even possible?

How can I migrate/connect my set of network / nodes with the test / private network?

So far was able to connect my existing nodes  to the stellar test network, but I don't think it's a right way to do things.

Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no interoperability between different networks.